# Export a PSD to compressed and transparent TIF files with only one layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, file-size

I have several packshot images inside a group (with a mask to have a transparent background) and a shadow layer at the bottom.

Is there any way to export all images in TIF files with only one layer and transparency?

I tried with Layer Comps but I have every layers in each file, so that's about 500mb for each (instead of ~15mb).

I have the CC 2015 version.

Comment: Depending on how many layers there are, it might be easier to delete the layers manually. Just delete the layers you do not want included into the tif file with 1 showing and then export. Repeat for the other layers. Maybe you can do a data merge in Photoshop if the images are already separate.

Comment: You are using a single mask for all layers? Do you want to export the groups as tiffs, right?

Comment: @poor: I have only one group with a mask and all the images inside

Comment: Ok, if you are able to write javascript - there is a script called *Export all Layers as Files*. I'd try to modify it in order to apply the mask first and export the Layer afterwards.

Comment: @poor: yep I know that script but the aim is to find an existing tool, as it's very specific I'll probably don't redo it

Comment: Yeah, it's not that typical workflow. I've already written a script to export folders/groups that I could share, but when I have time I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Can't you just merge the whole group together? (right click group --> merge). It will create a one layer file with transparency. I must be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @go-me: hm nope, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. The challenge is to add as many imported smart layer images as I need.

Comment: Indeed, not that simple. Someone just posted a script as answer, might work for you! I wouldn't know how to do it in one step only, maybe 2-3. Something like exporting all the layers in one doc each, and then creating an action to open these files, add the mask/shadow, merging if necessary and then save them.

Comment: The script was written with the existing export script in mind to achieve the desired functionality with less effort. It is also conceivable to concat both scripts... so let us know what else you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script, which **copies the layer mask of the selected group to all layers in the group itself**. Use *Export Layers to Files* script afterwards in order to export your layers to the desired file type (shipped with photoshop by default).

[image]

1. Backup your photoshop file first
2. Select the group/folder in the layer stack
3. Select and run the script via *File > Scripts > Browse*

**Copy-groupMask-to-groupLayers.jsx**

```
#target Photoshop

// pass the layer name
function copy_mask(targetLayer) {

    $.writeln(targetLayer);

    var desc126 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc126.putClass( charIDToTypeID('Nw  '), charIDToTypeID('Chnl') );

    var ref111 = new ActionReference();
    ref111.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Msk ') );
    ref111.putName( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), targetLayer.toString() );
    desc126.putReference( charIDToTypeID('At  '), ref111 );

    var ref112 = new ActionReference();
    ref112.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Msk ') );
    ref112.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
    desc126.putReference( charIDToTypeID('Usng'), ref112 );
    desc126.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID('Dplc'), true );

    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Mk  '), desc126, DialogModes.NO );
};

// get the document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// get the selection
var group = doc.activeLayer;

// iterate through the layers and copy the mask
for (var i=0; i<group.layers.length; i++){
    copy_mask(group.layers[i].name);
}
```